# How to fix the little space in when hovering in menu?

Tags: html, css, hover

When hovering the text it should have full width background effects, but as you can see there's a little space at the right side of background and it should reach to the top for full effects. I want to make it full background effects slide to top. I really appreciate your help.

its between About and Shop, You can see it in Blog text also at the last menu text.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IUXA.png)

[Codepen code](https://codepen.io/TrashCode/pen/VwjoVVa?editors=1100)

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.pdng-3 {
  padding: 30px;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #45372C;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}

li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 30px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
}

 li a:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: #9F8066;
    transform: scaleY(0);
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transition: transform .4s ease-in-out;
    
  }
  
  li a:hover:before,
  li a:active:before,
  li a:focus:before {
    transform: scaleY(1);
    transition: .4s;
    color: #ffffff;
    
  }
  
  li a {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative; 
   
  }
```

```html
<nav class="pdng-3">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Story</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your bug, there is no space on my end.

Comment: Seems to work fine in both Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I just went ahead and stress tested this and also cannot replicate the issue. It is likely that whatever you have placed above the NAV on your side is causing the issue and/or your specific browser running the site.

In all views, everything is working fine. I have even added a few lines of unnecessary content above the NAV and it does not seem to break anything.

I also suggest reading on how to make your NAV bar responsive (if you are not already doing so)

Best of luck!